# Updating score on every keypress, even on pressing backspace jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i update my total score with a multiplyer, i have international with a multiplyer of 5, and national with 3 and local with 2, how can i update automatically my total score?

```
 <body>
  International<input type="text" class="margininter" id="inter1" value="" />
  National<input type="text"     class="marginnation" id="nation1" value=""/)
  Local<input type="text"    class="marginlocal" id="local1" value=""/>
  Total: <input type="text" class="threetext" id="totalresearch" value="0" readonly/>
 </body>
```

here is my Jquery code for international

```
 $("#inter1").keyup(function () {
    var sum = parseInt($("#totalresearch").val()) + parseInt($(this).val()) *    parseInt('5');
      if (isNaN(sum)){
        alert('no to NaN');
        }else{
     $("#totalresearch").val(sum);

 });
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want the __Total__ value to be updated when one of the textboxes change? What is the formula to update __Total__? The sum of all?

Comment: Yes, i want to update every time the textbox changes, and the sum of Internationa, national, and local is just addition

Comment: there is  a logical issue with the calculation since you are using the value of `totalresearch`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wP6wY/1/

Comment: if you type 1 then delete and type 2 you gets a wrong result

Comment: what will i do to not get that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
International<input type="text" class="margininter" id="inter1" value="" data-cost="5"/>
National<input type="text"     class="marginnation" id="nation1" value="" data-cost="3"/>
Local<input type="text"    class="marginlocal" id="local1" value="" data-cost="2"/>
Total: <input type="text" class="threetext" id="totalresearch" value="0" readonly />
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $ins = $('#inter1, #nation1, #local1').keyup(function () {
        var sum = 0;

        $ins.each(function () {
            sum += parseInt(this.value) * $(this).data('cost') || 0;
        })

        $("#totalresearch").val(sum || 0);
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wP6wY/)